# Capitalize first char and leave others as is

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I only want to capitalize the first char and leave the others as is.

For example:

`"fooBar".titleize` returns `"Foo Bar"`. Should return **FooBar**.

`"foo_Bar".capitalize` returns `"Foo_bar"` Should return **Foo_Bar**.

Any way I can do this?

Comment: If you want to leave the others as is, why does `fooBar` become `Foobar` (note the `b`)? Is that a typo or do you want it downcased?

Comment: @Bryan I didn't understand that as well

Comment: Yea its a typo. Edited as appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "foo_Bar"
=> "foo_Bar"
irb(main):002:0> s[0] = s[0].upcase
=> "F"
irb(main):003:0> s
=> "Foo_Bar"
```

Or with regex for in-place substitution:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "foo_Bar"
=> "foo_Bar"
irb(main):002:0> s.sub!(/^\w/) {|x| x.upcase}
=> "Foo_Bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class String
  def fazzinize
    first, *last = self.split("_")
    [first.capitalize, *last].join("_")
  end
end

"fooBar".fazzinize
#=> "Foobar"
"foo_Bar".fazzinize
#=> "Foo_Bar"
```

**UPD**

if it is a typo:

> "fooBar".titleize returns "Foo Bar". Should return Foobar -> FooBar

then @Mchi is right

```
class String
  def fazzinize
    self[0] = self[0].upcase; self;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "foo_Bar"
=> "foo_Bar"
irb(main):002:0> s1 = s.slice(0,1).capitalize + s.slice(1..-1)
=> "Foo_Bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [substitute](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.src/M001185.html) the first character with its uppercase version using a block.

```
"fooBar".sub(/^./) { |char| char.upcase }
```